# Override Magento Contacts Controller

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to override `Mage/Contacts/IndexController.php`

I created a folder in local and created `Mynamespace/CustomContacts/controllers/IndexController.php`

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php';

class Mynamespace_CustomContacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController {

    protected function indexAction () {
        die;
    }
}
```

I also put this code in `Mynamespace/CustomContacts/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                     <modules>
                        <Mynamespace_CustomContacts before="Mage_Contacts">Mynamespace_CustomContacts</Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I cleaned the cache, but my die; does not work,

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Best practices

Your `config.xml` file seems like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mynamespace_CustomContacts before="Mage_Contacts">Mynamespace_CustomContacts</Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

### 2. Bad practices

You can move your controller in `app/local/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php` for a hard override.

**And don't forget to enable your module in xml file in app/etc/modules directory**

Comment: Thanks for answer, my XML was not complete, I agree and fixed it !
I also forgot to enable the module, I created Mynamespace_CustomContacts.xml in app/etc/modules with the followed code :
``<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>

    <modules>
        <Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
    </modules>
</config>
``
but it does not change anything .. Any idea what I missed ? 
Thank you again for your time

Comment: your xml file seems good, except maybe `encoding="UTF-8"` in xml declaration.

try with :

`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config>
  <modules>
   <Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>local</codePool>
   </Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
  </modules>
</config>`

Answer (score 0):

Go through this, It overrides the `IndexController.php` from `Mage_Contacts`
http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

IndexController.php file ( local/your_company/your_block_name/controllers/

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Contacts').DS.'IndexController.php';

class IGN_Siteblocks_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
}
```

local/your_company/your_block_name/etc/config.xml

```
<contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <siteblocks before="Mage_Contacts">IGN_Siteblocks</siteblocks>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
```

And Let`s go to create your sample code like this :

```
class IGN_Siteblocks_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
   public function createAction()
{
    return $this->_redirect('noroute');
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Before getting to the answer I want to know have to defined your custom module in `config.xml` file.

I think that is missing here.

Add

```
<modules>
        <Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Mynamespace_CustomContacts>
    </modules>
```

after config node in `config.xml` file.

Also

```
<Mynamespace_CustomContacts before="Mage_Contacts">
    Mynamespace_CustomContacts
</Mynamespace_CustomContacts>`
```

it should be in small letters like below

```
<mynamespace_customcontacts before="Mage_Contacts">
     Mynamespace_CustomContacts
</mynamespace_customcontacts>`
```

Hope this will solve your problem.