# Magento IndexController override not working

Tags: magento

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong here but I've been looking at the code for several hours now and I can't seem to fix it.

So here's the problem:
I want to override the IndexController in /core/Contacts/controllers to redirect to a custom page after submitting the contact form. It works when I make changes in the core file but we all know this is not the way to go.

My config.xml(app/code/local/Namespace/ContactRedirect/etc/**config.xml**):

```
<config>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <contactredirect before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_ContactRedirect</contactredirect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My IndexController(app/code/local/Namespace/ContactRedirect/controllers/**IndexController.php**):

```
<?php

require_once(Mage::getModuleDir("controllers", "Mage_Contacts").DS."IndexController.php");

class Namespace_ContactRedirect_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController {

public function postAction() {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            //$this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('contact-form', array('_secure' => true)));

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            //$this->_redirect('*/*/');
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('contact-form', array('_secure' => true)));
            return;
        }

    } else {
        //$this->_redirect('*/*/');
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('contact-form', array('_secure' => true)));
    }
}

}
```

Edit: Magento cache is disabled.

Comment: Check this : [Override Magento Contacts Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30477230/override-magento-contacts-controller/30477461#30477461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...
And I have to say sorry and thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
It was a stupid typo at the top of etc/config.xml.

Here it comes:

Instead of `<?xml version="1.0"?>` I had `<?xml version="1.0?>`
See the missing " after 1.0...

I blame my Editor for not marking it :P

Next time I'll post the whole file...

Again big thanks @All and sry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 0):

You probably made a mistake in the `config.xml` in the `<modules>` tag,

```
<config>    
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_ContactRedirect before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_ContactRedirect</Namespace_ContactRedirect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer but it sadly still doesn't work.
I read somewhere that you can give that tag any name you want when overriding controllers, thats why I left it all small.

Comment: did u replace the Namespace with MP ?

Comment: Yes. I only used "Namespace" here as referrence. But on my side it's "MP".
(sry for confusion)

Answer (score 0):

Hey there is problem with etc/config.xml file please check it out twice i have same code running perfectly.Let me know if still have any query and also message me here

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It feels like I have checked that file about a hundred times and I can't find any errors. You can take a look at it, it's on the main post. Maybe you can share your etc/config.xml with us so I can compare them. Though it's good to know that the IndexController.php seems to work.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <Namespace_ContactRedirect>
   <version>0.1.0</version>
  </Namespace_ContactRedirect>
 </modules>
 <frontend>
  <routers>
      <contacts>
          <args>
              <modules>
                  <contactredirect before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_ContactRedirect</contactredirect>
              </modules>
          </args>
      </contacts>
  </routers>
     </frontend>
</config>

Comment: Thank you though I already found the (stupid) mistake. I have answered this question by myself (look a few answers above/below yours) but I can't upvote or mark it as 'correct answer' within 2 days.

Comment: Please let me know where did you a mistake Thanks

Comment: At the very top of the xml file. I had <?xml version="1.0?> but it should be <?xml version="1.0"?>. I was missing a "...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<config>
 <modules>
  <Namespace_ContactRedirect>
   <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Namespace_ContactRedirect>
</modules>
<frontend>
<routers>
 <contacts>
  <args>
   <modules>
    <contactredirect before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_ContactRedirect</contactredirect>
</modules>
</args>
</contacts>
</routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```